# Centered text being pushed over CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm going to make this question applicable to all viewers.

Question: How can I keep my centered div centered relative to the header, and also have another div at the same time to the side and not pushing the centered div over?

Whenever I add to my header, the centered title is being pushed over. I don't understand why this is happening since CSS is supposed to be relative to the parent.

CSS CODE:

```
#logout_link {
  margin-right:0;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}

#centered { 
  text-align:center;
}
```

PHP/HTML CODE:

```
 <div id='header'>
    <div id='centered'>Centered Title</div>
    <div id='logout_link'> Logout </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you gotten your CSS to work or not? Are you looking for a solution or explanation?

Comment: What do you mean by pushed over? Be clear!

Comment: #HavingDifficultiesThough

Comment: What is the problem exactly, how do you want it to look?

Comment: Im sorry for being too vague, I have edited my question.

Comment: @EugeneStamp What does your error look like? What are you trying to achieve? Your question is extremely vague and confusing.

Comment: The behaviour you describe does not occur with this html, you would need to switch the two inner divs for that to happen...

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
<style>
#header{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#logout_link {
  margin-right:0;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
  width:20%;
}

#centered { 
  text-align:center;
  width:80%;
  float:left;

}
</style>
 <div id='header'>
    <div id='centered'>Centered Title</div>
    <div id='logout_link'> Logout </div>
 </div>
```

You can change `width` of div on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking but try this:

```
#logout_link {
 margin-right:0;
 text-align:right;
 float:right;
 width: 100%;
}

#centered { 
 text-align:center !important;
 width:50%;
}

#logout_link { 
 text-align:center !important;
 width:50%;
}
```

I think the issue you are having is because you don't have any widths specified, play around with them if this is the solution you are looking for

Comment: Why the !important directive, and why you overwrite the #logout_link rules? It doesn't make sense

Comment: So that he can change them individually if need be, and important because I don't know what the rest of his stylesheet looks like or will look like